# I would like to fully erase my hard drive and start from a clean slate with Ubuntu

Tags: installation, format

How do I do that? Can I fully format the internal hard drive and then install Ubuntu, or would that leave all systems, including usb and cd drives unoperable.

Otherwise, how do I remove windows completely and install Ubuntu?

Thanks, sorry if this is too dumb a question.

Comment: Don't worry about the hardware not working - Linux does not use the same drivers as Windows, so erasing Windows will not effect how your hardware works in Linux.

Comment: Always remember to back up your data before doing a complete re-install like this. Whatever is currently on your disk isn't coming back. While you may be eager to lose Windows, don't lose your important data.

Answer (score 7):

You just boot the Ubuntu Desktop CD/USB and choose to install Ubuntu. When you get to the partitioning step, tell it to use the entire harddrive. It'll overwrite anything that is currently on the harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu, simply choose the option to use the entire hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [this webpage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) and follow the steps to install and if you look on the link at step 5, you want to select the second option (erase disk and install ubuntu) to achieve what you ask.

Your other drives will remain operational with or without an operating system installed
they are controlled by your bios not your OS .

Comment: be sure to backup all important data before doing that.. otherwise it might not be possible at all to recuperate such data..